# Why FXSAVE on Intel stores abridged x87 tags

Tags: x86, x87

The FXSAVE IA32 instruction does not save x87 native two-bits tags into the FTW byte of the save area.  Instead, 'an abridged tags', single bit *inverted* tags are saved.  I.e. (00, 01, 10) -> 1, 11 -> 0 for full->abridged translation.

I am asking for the factual reasons why Intel decided to do this.  I can imagine at least two reasons why, but these would be speculations, and more importantly, I do not understand why do they consider it worth to break binary compatibility, so thoroughly cared about otherwise. So I am asking somebody knowledgeable about the facts.

*[Removed false statement that AMD CPUs save full version]*

Comment: You may wish to read page 356 and 357 of the [AMD64 manual Volume 2](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/05au-cs240c/lab/amd64/AMD64-2.pdf) . It says _FXSAVE Format for x87 Tag Word. **Rather than saving the entire x87
tag word**, FXSAVE saves a **single-byte encoded version**_ It also tells you how you software can use the FPR register values to reconstitute the original TAG field.

Comment: The byte next to FTW is marked reserved, that is probably not an accident.  So original intention might well have been to save the tags as-is, requiring two bytes.  But then they he to do something ugly, having FXRSTOR generating a trap when the saved tags don't match the saved value.  Much easier to just not have to do that.  You'll have to ask the design engineer if you want a fact.  He's surely sipping pina-coladas on a sunny Pacific beach right now without a care in the world.  You shouldn't care either.

Comment: I have to :(.  I just fixed a bug with ptrace handling of x87 on 64bit and suspect one more.  So I want to know why it was thought of as useful.

Comment: When you restore the FPU state with an instruction like FXRSTOR the only thing that matters is if a register is marked empty or not. When the FPU state is restored with FXRSTOR the tag bit for the register is checked . If it is empty (0) then the register in the tag word of the FPU is marked as 11 (empty) and that register is loaded with the value. If it is not empty (1) then FXRSTOR will look at the data stored for that register and set the tag word for that register to match the data stored for that register.(00,10, or 11) and then store the saved value into the FPU register.

Comment: Determining the tag word state of a register when a register is marked non empty (00,01,10) also applies to instructions like FLDENV.

Comment: Older Intel documentation describes this behaviour: _"This action prevents a program from setting the values in the tag register to incorrectly
represent the actual contents of non-empty data registers."_ . The net effect of this is that a programmer can't directly set the 2-bit tag word state for a register that are marked non-empty (00,01,10)